# Using Perl Redis::Client::Hash can't locate object method "TIEHASH"

Tags: perl, redis

I am trying to use Redis::Client::Hash per the instructions, but keep getting 
"Can't locate object method "TIEHASH" via package "Redis::Client::Hash" at ./redishasttest.pl line 8."
Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Redis::Client;

my $client = Redis::Client->new;

tie( my %hash, "Redis::Client::Hash", key => 'hello', client => $client);

my @keys = keys %hash;
$hash{foo} = 42;
print 1 if exists $hash{foo};
```

Seems straightforward enough -- Perl version 5.10.1, Redis 2.6.14.  I am thinking it's a Moose thing or something, as the module has a TIEHASH sub.  Redis::Client::Hash is actually installed when you install Redis::Client, so everything there looks good. The same sort of thing happens with Redis::Client::String so can't TIESCALAR. Am I missing something?

After friedo's answer, the solution to check that a hash key is set in redis is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Redis::Client;
use Redis::Client::Hash;
my $key = 'hello';

my $client = Redis::Client->new;

# first make sure hash with key exists
if ($client->type($key) ne "hash") {
    print "$key not a hash\n";
    $client->hmset($key, dummy => 1);
}

tie( my %hash, "Redis::Client::Hash", key => $key, client => $client);

print "KEY     VALUE\n" if %hash > 0;
foreach my $k (keys %hash) {
    print "$k   $hash{$k}\n";
}
```

Thanks again for the nice group of modules!

Answer (score 2):

`Redis::Client` doesn't load the tie modules directly, so you just have to `use` them first.

```
use strict;
use Redis::Client;
use Redis::Client::Hash;  # <---- add this

my $client = Redis::Client->new;

# first create something
$client->hset( 'hello', some => 'thing' );

tie( my %hash, "Redis::Client::Hash", key => 'hello', client => $client);

my @keys = keys %hash;
$hash{foo} = 42;
print 1 if exists $hash{foo};
```

It looks like I need to clarify that in the docs. I can probably do a new release this weekend.

Comment: I wanted to constrain the question; I had already tried that.  Now there's a "Redis key hello is a none. Try using Redis::Client::None instead at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Redis/Client/Role/Tied.pm line 23, <GEN0> line 1." As far as I can tell Moose doesn't know that the key is a Str type, and comes up with "none." That's about where I started getting out of my knowledge. By the way, thanks for the module. I really want to use it, pardon the pun!

Comment: That's not Moose, it's just due to the poor way in which I handle Redis keys that [don't exist](http://redis.io/commands/type). Just make sure you create the key before trying to `tie` it. I'll update the example in the answer.

Comment: And actually, the `TIEHASH` method should be smart enough to autovivify the object on the server if it doesn't yet exist. I'll add that feature too. :)